# Spring Boot + Quartz : Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic, quartz

We have a spring boot application which uses apache quartz for scheduling jobs. The application restarts( automatically) after first quartz job's execution. Below are the logs, not sure why the application has stopped accepting traffic, even though we don't have any special configuration for this.

Note :

1. We are using WebLogic for deploying the spring boot app.
2. After the first spring boot restart, the application runs fine for all the other quartz jobs.

```
 10:58:10.889 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:10.889 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:10.889 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:10.889 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:10.890 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:10.890 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:10.890 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:10.890 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:10.890 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:10.890 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.053 Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3bb80721, started on Wed Oct 06 10:57:21 GMT 2021, parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5910edf1
 10:58:11.119 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.119 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.119 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.119 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.119 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.119 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.119 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.119 Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5910edf1, started on Wed Oct 06 10:57:17 GMT 2021, parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@688b20f7
 10:58:11.174 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.174 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.174 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.174 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.174 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.174 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.174 Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@688b20f7, started on Wed Oct 06 10:57:13 GMT 2021, parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2962a6b8
 10:58:11.238 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.238 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.238 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.238 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.238 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.238 Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2962a6b8, started on Wed Oct 06 10:57:08 GMT 2021, parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6bbdca9
 10:58:11.304 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.304 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.304 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.304 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.304 Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6bbdca9, started on Wed Oct 06 10:57:04 GMT 2021, parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@51e81568
 10:58:11.416 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.416 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.416 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.416 Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@51e81568, started on Wed Oct 06 10:57:00 GMT 2021, parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@4a73f717
 10:58:11.472 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.472 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.473 Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@4a73f717, started on Wed Oct 06 10:56:55 GMT 2021, parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@536a1c93
 10:58:11.535 Application availability state ReadinessState changed from REFUSING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
 10:58:11.535 Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@536a1c93, started on Wed Oct 06 10:56:37 GMT 2021
 10:58:11.538 Stopping beans in phase 2137484647
```

Comment: Is quartz running on the same pool as the one used to handle requests?